# How can I set default application on pepper robot tablet?

Tags: pepper

I have created a simple web application to render on pepper tablet and I want to set the application as default startup app. how can I do that?

Comment: What version of Naoqi are you using? What kind of "web app" are you referring to?

Comment: I am using Naoqi version 2.5.10. It is a simple static web page which contains an index page and some javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "Launch trigger condition" to "1".

These can be set in the manifest of the Choregrahe behavior of the activity.

Check the documentation [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/panels/project_content_panel.html#chore-project-content):

More about trigger conditions can be found [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/triggerconditions.html):